# Protractor - Appium -

Tags: javascript, protractor, appium, screen-resolution, angularjs-e2e

I am able to run automated tests both on Desktop, Mobile devices using Protractor + Appium.  However having issues to run custom test, that work only in Desktop/Mobile only.

for eg: One of my test validates Breadcrumbs, which are displayed only in Desktop screen resolution.

Would you please advise, if there is a solution to check if test is being executed in Desktop or Mobile.

```
eg; it('check breadcrumb in website', function(){
       if(isDesktop()){
         contentItemPage.checkBreadCrumb();  
       }
    });
```

Similar to the following, to check if browser is Chrome or not.

```html
 function isChromeBrowser(){ 
          browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
               if(config.capabilities.browserName.valueOf() === new String('chrome').valueOf()){
                    return true;
               } 

               return false;
              
              
       
          });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would you be able to use the [appium capabilities](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities) and check the platformName?

```
function isMobileBrowser(){
          browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
               if(config.capabilities.platformName.valueOf() === new String('Android').valueOf() || new String('iOS').valueOf()){
                    return true;
               }

               return false;

          });
}
```